# How to write a Spring Cloud Contract contract for endpoint that uses @ModelAttribute parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cloud

This is the endpoint I'm trying to write a SCC contract for. It consumes form data as a DTO and processes it.

```
PostMapping(value = "/bar/process", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  public List<Foo> processBar(
      @ModelAttribute("data") BarDto barDto) {
    return barService.processBar(barDto);
  }
```

I cannot figure out how to write a groovy contract for this endpoint. I know how to write contract tests for controllers that use multipart form data using `@RequestPart` annotation, but here - I'm lost.

Can you even use CC with Spring MVC elements?

I'm using SCC version 2.2.7.

Comment: please any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @hichamabdedaime It's been a while, I don't really remember :D

as far as I remember I realized that I'm combining two uncompatible parts - a REST-based library (Cloud Contract) and a MVC element (`ModelAttribute`). 

I think I just rewrote the controller to skip using `ModelAttribute` completely